Getting rid of "Sign-in error" notification on Xiaomi device?
I sold my old Xiaomi 9 Lite and bought a Xiaomi 12.
The "Sign-in error" keeps appearing constantly.

The old device is disconnected from Xiaomi Cloud, Xiaomi Account, and also from the Google Account. I logged off and on there too.
What else can I do to prevent the annoying notification?

A new device that has problems with login - this sounds to me more like a case for Xiaomi support.

Related/possible dupe: Why the "Sign-in error" notification appear on Xiaomi device?
